# Knight tour (backtrack)

Tags: java, backtracking, knights-tour

I am trying to solve Knight's tour problem with 8*8 chessboard. But my backtrack is going in infinite loop. My Logic function is as follows:-

N is 8.

```
  boolean algo(int x,int y,int no_of_moves,int sol[][]){

        if(no_of_moves==N*N){
            return true;
        }

        int nextx;
        int nexty;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){

            nextx=x+move_x[i];
            nexty=y+move_y[i];

            if(is_valid(nextx,nexty)){
                sol[nextx][nexty]=no_of_moves;

                if(algo(nextx,nexty,no_of_moves+1,sol)){
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    sol[nextx][nexty]=-1;

            }
        }
        return false;  
    }
```

sol [][] stores the moves made by the knight.

the array move_x and move_y stores the values to be added to x and y to get next position of knight.

```
 int move_x[]={  2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1,  1,  2 };
    int move_y[]={  1, 2,  2,  1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
```

I started by passing x as 0, y as 0, no_of_moves as 1, and all values in sol[][] as -1
except sol[0][0] as 0.

And `is_valid()` checks if the `nextx`, and `nexty` is inside the chessboard and not visited yet.

```
boolean is_valid(int xnext,int ynext)
    {
        if(xnext>=0 && xnext<N && ynext>=0 && ynext<N && sol[xnext][ynext]==-1)
        { 
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im pretty sure its not infinite. Its more like number_of_moves^(N*N). Are you sure you check if you already visited the field correctly? The easy way to do it is to just run it on really small board, like 3x3, and check if it actually ends.

Comment: You might want to include your `is_valid()` method in the question, in case there's something wrong with it.

Comment: boolean is_valid(int xnext,int ynext){
        if(xnext>=0&&xnext<N&&ynext>=0&&ynext<N&&sol[xnext][ynext]==-1){
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. I suspect that it doesn't go into an *infinite* loop, but into one that takes a long time.

See if it works on a 5x5 board ([animation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Knights-Tour-Animation.gif)).

Comment: I put System.out.println(no_of_moves); to see where it is stuck, it is showing as:-52
50
51
52
52
53
52
51
52
53
50
51
51
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
 ... means stuck in 50's

Comment: @user3423663: But that doesn't really prove anything, does it? Or am I missing your point here?

Comment: No.i was just saying that it really goes to infinite loop, not long time.Well i will try to see my full code again, but really i don't know how it's happening.

Comment: @user3423663: I still don't follow your argument for why you think the loop is infinite, but I am going to leave it at that.

Comment: Ya You were right @NPE. It is not going infinite, it is taking a very very long time. It took me 5 sec for 5*5 and 14 sec for 6*6 chessboard, and for 8*8 it has taken more than 13 min and still no solution. Thanks. Well then which algo i should use?

Comment: @user3423663: You could try Warnsdorff's rule: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_tour#Warnsdorff.27s_rule (also see the rest of the article for other approaches).

Comment: Your algorithm seems to work fine when I tried it. At least for a 8x8 board, with the starting point 0,4 (the example on wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using brute force there, but that isn't enough to solve this problem in reasonable time. Without optimisations, complexity will be `O(N^(N*N))` (with N being the board dimension). Thus it may really take an eternity of time to find the first solution. That's why you thought it was on an infinite loop.

The most efficient optimisation is [Warnsdorff's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff%27s_rule), which was first published in 1823. It's a kind of simple heuristic rule which allows you to find a solution on the first try (immediately).